# If I can't define a variable inside an if-condition, how can I reduce searching through my array multiple times in this code?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function who's body looks a lot like this:

```
if (contains(array, element1) > -1){
        // do something
    } else if (contains(array, element2) > -1) {
        // do something
    } else if (contains(array, element3) > -1) {
        // do someting
    }...
```

The function `contains` will loop through my array and check to see if it contains an `element` that I pass to it and return either its position if it exists, or -1 if it doesn't.

In my `// do something` portion, I need the position of this element in the array. There are a couple of different ways I can do this:

1. I can call my `contains()` function once more to get the position.
2. I can define several variables that are defined as the return of the contain function, and then check them in my if-else block. So something like:

   ```
   int element1Loc = contains(array, element1);
   int element2Loc = contains(array, element2);
   int element3Loc = contains(array, element3);

   if (element1Loc > -1){
       // do something
   } else if (element2Loc > -1) {
       // do something
   } else if (element3Loc > -1) {
       // do someting
   }...
   ```
3. I can perhaps modify `contain` to return an `int array[2]`, with `array[0]` equal to `0` or `1` whether the element is in it or not, and then `array[1]` qwould equal the actual location, making the code look like thiss:

   ```
   if (contains(array, element1)[0] > -1){
       // do something
   } else if (contains(array, element2)[0] > -1) {
       // do something
   } else if (contains(array, element3)[0] > -1) {
       // do something
   }...
   ```
4. I can say screw the if-else block, save the return of `contains` in a variable and run several if-statements.

Solution one will search through my array at least twice. Solution two will search at least as many times as there are elements I'm looking for. Solution 3 is perhaps the best, but maybe not the most elegant. Solution 4 will run each if statement...

What is the best way to search just once? Should I make a function that takes all the things I am looking for and returns an array with the position of each element? Am I overthinking it?

Comment: Not pretty, but you can do `int elementLoc; ... if ((elementLoc = contains(array, element1)) > -1) { ...`. So you use only one variable, which is computed only when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify `contains` to only use the return value to indicate the error/success of the find, and, if the parameter was found, output the parameter by reference.

```
int contains(int *data, int value, int *loc)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
         if(data[i]==value)
         {
              *loc = i;
              return 1; // success
         }
    }
    *loc = -1;
    return 0; // failure
}
```

Now, you can just do:

```
int elem1loc, elem2loc, elem3loc;
if(contains(data, val1, &elem1loc))
     // use elem1loc...
if(contains(data, val2, &elem2loc))
     // use elem2loc...
```

Comment: *thats* awesome. I did not know you could point to an `int` like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a pointer to say `int` which would be populated when the contains function finds an element. Then inside your `if` block you would be assured that `pos` is the correct index.

Example:

```
int pos;

if (contains(array, element1, &pos) > -1) {
    // Here you can check pos for the position
} else if (contains(array, element2, &pos) > -1) {
    // Here you can check pos as well...
}
```

Comment: Govind provided an answer sooner and "more complete" than you, so I am accepting his, but this is IMO equally awesome. I especially like that you did not instantiate several variables, which I don't think you need to do (as Gavin did). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't require you to modify `contains` at all:

```c
int pos;

if ((pos = contains(array, element1)) > -1) {
    // do something with pos
} else if ((pos = contains(array, element2)) > -1) {
    // do something with pos
} else if ((pos = contains(array, element3)) > -1) {
    // do something with pos
}
```

This works because variable assignment in most imperative languages is an expression.